# Show that in a graph with minimum degree $\delta$, each component must contain at least $\delta+1$ vertices.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that in a graph with minimum degree $\delta$, each component must contain at least $\delta+1$ vertices.

I have tried a few different approaches, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. Let $G$ be a disconnected graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ components. I assumed that each component has at most $\delta$ vertices and tried to reach a contradiction using The First Theorem of Graph Theory. I have that $2m=\sum_{i=0}^n\deg_G(v_i)\geq n\delta$ and that $2m=\sum_{i=0}^n\deg_G(v_i)\leq kn\delta$. However, I feel this is wrong and isn't helping. Maybe a direct proof or an induction proof might work. Any solutions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a connected component of $\delta$ (or fewer) vertices, the maximum degree each vertex can have is $\delta-1$, achieved when that component is $K_\delta$. Any more edges would have to go out of the "wall" surrounding the connected component (i.e. into another component), increasing the minimum degree.