# Proof about number of degrees in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following problem: suppose there is a graph of $n\geq2$ vertices, each of which has at least $p\geq1$ degrees. I need to prove that if $p> \frac{n-2}{2}$, then this graph has exactly one connected component. I tried different approaches, but they did not lead me to the proof. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Prove the contrapositive. (What is it? how can we show it?)

Comment: I would suggest assuming there is a minimally sized counterexample with at least two disconnected components, and consider how complete the graphs are in those components

Comment: I tried to assume the contrapositive (more than one component leads to p <..., but i could not derive the formula from this assumtion anyway )

Comment: You can use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115812/show-that-in-a-graph-with-minimum-degree-delta-each-component-must-contain-a) to help.

Comment: I can actually come up with a single scenario for counterexample. But it still does not lead me to general proof. I would appreciate any additional hint.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two arbitrary vertices $a$ and $b$ in the graph. If they are adjacent, then they are connected. If $a$ and $b$ are not adjacent, then the closed neighbourhoods $N[a]$ and $N[b]$ of $a$ and $b$ respectively, contain at least $p+1$ vertices. If $N[a]$ and $N[b]$ are disjoint, then we get at least $2p+2>n-2+2=n$ vertices in $G$, a contradiction. Thus $N[a]$ and $N[b]$ intersects and hence $G$ is connected.